# How to show that $Z(I(T))=\overline{T}$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

I am studying algebraic curves and there is a theorem establishes an inclusion reversing correspondence between subsets of the affine space $\mathbb A^n_k$ and the ideals of $k[X_1,X_2,...,X_n]$ ($k$ being an algebraically closed field).For that we first need to know some notions:

Suppose $S\subset k[X_1,X_2,...,X_n]$ then $Z(S)$ denotes the set of all common zeros of polynomials in $S$.Again,suppose $T\subset \mathbb A_k^n$ then the ideal of $T$ denoted by $I(T)=\{f\in k[X_1,X_2,...,X_n]:f(t)=0,\forall t\in T\}$.

Now I claim that $Z(I(T))=\overline T$,i.e. the closure of $T$ in Zariski topology.Now we need to show that $Z(I(T))$ is the smallest closed/algebraic set containing $T$.Clearly $Z(I(T))$ is closed and $T\subset Z(I(T))$ but now I want to show that it is the smallest,i.e. if $T\subset F$ and $F$ is closed/algebraic,then $Z(I(T))\subset F$.But I am not able to show that,I am confused how to approach the problem.Can someone help me?

Comment: What is the definition of " closure of $T$ in Zariski topology" again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say $T\subset Z(J)$ for some ideal $J$, we want to show that $ZI(T)\subset Z(J)$ as well.

Note that $I(\cdot)$ and $Z(\cdot)$ are both inclusion-reversed.

So $T\subset Z(J)$ implies $I(T)\supset IZ(J)$ so $ZI(T)\subset ZIZ(J)$.

It remains to show that $ZIZ(J)=Z(J)$.

Note that for any subset $S\subset k[X_1,\dots,X_n]$ and $T\subset \mathbb{A}_k^n$, we have $S\subset IZ(S)$ and $T\subset ZI(T)$, it can be proved by just checking the definitions.

So we have $J\subset IZ(J)$. Apply $Z(\cdot)$ to both sides we have $Z(J)\supset ZIZ(J)$.

Denote $T^\prime=Z(J)$, we have $Z(J)=T^\prime\subset ZI(T^\prime)=ZI(Z(J))$.

It follows that $ZIZ(J)=Z(J)$. The result follows.

Comment: your solution is not clear to me.

Comment: specially the last part,please elaborate.

Comment: @KishalaySarkar I have edited it, let me know if there are other unclearness.